# using Fluid Parser binding the list to html template

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluid

using fluid parser I need to bind the data to the html template but loop is iterating but data is not binding

```cs
if (parser.TryParse(source1, out var template, out var error))
{
    var options = new TemplateOptions { Trimming = TrimmingFlags.TagRight };
    var context = new TemplateContext(options);
    context.SetValue("listofTransactionModel", listofTransactionModel);
    options.Filters.AddFilter("previousbalance", (input, args, ctx) => input);
    options.Filters.AddFilter("currentbalance", (input, args, ctx) => input);
    options.Filters.AddFilter("credittransactionamount", (input, args, ctx) => input);
    options.Filters.AddFilter("debittransactionamount", (input, args, ctx) => input);
    options.Filters.AddFilter("activitytype", (input, args, ctx) => input);
    options.MemberAccessStrategy.Register(new { previousbalance = 0, currentbalance = 0, credittransactionamount = 0, debittransactionamount = 0, activitytype = "" }.GetType());

    var result = template.Render(context);

    Console.WriteLine(template.Render(context));
}
```

Html Template:

```
<html>
    {% for listofTransactionModel in listofTransactionModel %}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{listofTransactions.previousbalance}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{listofTransactions.currentbalance}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{listofTransactions.credittransactionamount}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{listofTransactions.debittransactionamount}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{listofTransactions.activitytype}}
        </td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to whitelist any objects you want to access in your template.  So say your "listofTransactionModel" is a List of the class TransactionModel.  Then you need to add this to your options:

```
options.MemberAccessStrategy.Register<TransactionModel>();
```

So your code would be:

```
if (parser.TryParse(source1, out var template, out var error))
{
    var options = new TemplateOptions { Trimming = TrimmingFlags.TagRight };
    options.MemberAccessStrategy.Register<TransactionModel>();
    var context = new TemplateContext(options);
    context.SetValue("listofTransactionModel", listofTransactionModel);
    options.Filters.AddFilter("previousbalance", (input, args, ctx) => input);
    options.Filters.AddFilter("currentbalance", (input, args, ctx) => input);
    options.Filters.AddFilter("credittransactionamount", (input, args, ctx) => input);
    options.Filters.AddFilter("debittransactionamount", (input, args, ctx) => input);
    options.Filters.AddFilter("activitytype", (input, args, ctx) => input);
    options.MemberAccessStrategy.Register(new { previousbalance = 0, currentbalance = 0, credittransactionamount = 0, debittransactionamount = 0, activitytype = "" }.GetType());

    var result = template.Render(context);

    Console.WriteLine(template.Render(context));
}
```

Hope this helps.  I wrestled with this as well.